# Can't able to change JDK 1.5.0 to JDK 1.7.0 in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build, android-gradle-plugin

I can't change the JDK Version on android studio, even though I gave correct JDK path from 1.5 to 1.7. It will change back to the old path for 1.5, and due to this I can't build the project.

I have even tried changing environmental variable using `JDK_HOME`.

[Changing to my current JDK Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pso5H.png)

[Selecting JDK 1.7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eDFi.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would try deleting the old JDK's and reinstalling only the newer so that I can't pick the old one. (Also try just deleting the old one first, but I suspect this problem may have to do with the new one being corrupt in some way.) Also try saving your projects elsewhere and then reinstalling Android Studio.